# Finding Context Free grammar (CFG)

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-languages, automata-theory

> Give a context free grammar H that generates the language
>
> ```
>  M = {a^m
> b^n
> | 2m > n > m}.
> ‘
> ```
>
> Hint: m can’t be 0, because in that case 2m = m. m can’t be 1, because in that case 2 > n > 1, such a natural
>   number n doesn’t exist. So the shortest string in the language M is aabbb. For longer strings, you need to make sure
>   that the number n of bs and the number m of as satisfy 2m > n > m.

Comment: If you want help with this homework question you want https://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not belong to stack-overflow and it belongs to other website, possibly https://cs.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @DavisHerring: This question was already asked on [cs.se], possibly by the same poster, and almost immediately closed, as a crosspost, as it happens, but also because [cs.se] strongly discourages "do my homework for me" questions.

Comment: @rici: Agreed.  I didn’t say it would be warmly welcomed, and I called it homework explicitly for a reason.

Comment: @DavisHerring: Perhaps there is a market for do-my-homework.stackexchange.com, but as far as I know, it is not even in beta. (Although I'm often surprised by the tolerance of [math.se] denizens.) I generally try to discourage recommendations to use [cs.se] for questions which clearly do not meet the standards for that site; it's just creating extra work for volunteer moderators.

Comment: @rici: Fair enough.  Being off-topic seems more fundamental (and more objective, since it doesn't depend on other sites' standards) than being poorly researched (aka homework), but I'll try to remember to favor the latter when it'd be harmful to do otherwise.

Comment: @rici "do my homework for me" is off topic here too, oddly enough the question is still open, upvoted and even answered..

Answer (score 1):

We know `aabbb` is in the language, so `S -> aabbb` isn't a bad start. How do we get longer strings in the language? Well, we need to keep `2m > n > m`. The shortest strings (for a given number of `a`s) in this language have one more `b` than they have `a`, so we might guess that `S -> aSb` is not a bad guess; it certainly generates strings in our language, namely, the shortest ones (for a given number of `a`s). Similarly, the longest strings in our language have one fewer `b` than twice as many `a` as they have, so `S -> aSbb` is also safe in that it generates the longest strings (for a given number of `a`s). Our grammar so far is this:

```
S -> aabbb
S -> aSb
S -> aSbb
```

Every production after the first adds a single `a` and either one or two `b`s. The second production can be used alone to generate the shortest strings (for a given number of `a`s) and the third, when used alone, generates the longest ones (for a given number of `a`s). What about the strings in between the shortest and longest ones? Can these productions be used to get all of those strings too?

They can. You can prove it by induction. You have to show that all strings of length `n` (1) in the language are generated by the grammar and (2) generated by the grammar are in the language.

Base case: the shortest string in the language is `aabbb` and it is generated by the grammar.

Induction hypothesis: assume the grammar generates all and only strings in the language for any string up to and including length `k`.

Induction step: we must show the grammar generates all and only strings in the language for any string of length `k + 1`. We have already argued that the grammar cannot produce a string not in the language; by using the second production only, you get `n = m + 1`, and by using the third production only you get `n = 2m - 1`. To see that it generates all strings in the language, recall that any string in the language starts with at least two `a`s and ends with at least three `b`s. So, it can be written as `aaxbbb`. It can be shown that if this string is in the language, then one or both of `axbb` and/or `axb` must also be in the language.

1. `axbb` is in `L` if `2(m - 1) > n - 1 > m - 1`, or `2m - 1 > n > m`
2. `axb` is in `L` if `2(m - 1) > n - 2 > m - 1`, or `2m > n > m + 1`.

Since in every case starting with the base case we have at least one of `2m - 1 > n` and/or `n > m + 1`, one of those is also in `L`. By the induction hypothesis, the grammar generates it; and one of the grammar's productions will produce from it the original string of length `k + 1`. So the grammar generates all strings in `L`.